# Is it ok to use png as a button background?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

Is there is any drawback of using `png` as a background for a `Button` or `EditText`. Or should I write a code for `XML` for background of Button or EditText. I want to know which is the better way.

Comment: Avoid PNG or JPG images as backgrounds, untill you can accomplish UI design using Shape Drawables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use color,drawable file or image as background

Color

```
android:background="#2F6699"
```

Drawable

```
android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
```

Image

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

Drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:thickness="0dp"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#2F6699"/>

    <corners android:radius="3dp" />

    <gradient   android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:type="linear"
                android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try **9 patch** image for button and edittext background.

**9 Patch:**

> 9-Patch images are stretchable, repeatable images reduced to their
>   smallest size; users draw a right and bottom, solid black 1 pixel
>   border to tell the system how to place the content within the image.

For more information visit this post:

[Utility of android nine patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684960/utility-of-android-nine-patch/22685252)

Answer (score 0):

just put png image into drawable, and than set it in xml via android:background="@drawable/image.png"

Answer (score 0):

Use it in button properties

```
android:background="@drawable/imageName"
```